# Raspberry Pi4, mariadb install, mysql comand not found problem

Tags: mysql, mariadb

HI Folks I have installed mariadb on a raspberry pi using pip3 and a wheel package. I don't have internet access on the pi so had to do a pip download with dependencies on another machine and copy it across. When I do a 'pip3 show mariadb' command, I get the following:

```
Version: 1.0.7
Summary: Python MariaDB extension
Home-page: https://www.github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python
Author: Georg Richter
Author-email: None
License: LGPL 2.1
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

From this I assume that it installed ok but I can't seem to run it using the 'mysql -u root -p' command. I get a 'mysql: command not found' error. Do I have to edit my PATH and if so how can I find the path to the application? I have done a full file search for 'mysql' but only get a couple of files that I know what they are, but they are not the main application.

This is how I installed mariadb:

```
pi@PTGM2:~/mariadb-deps $ pip3 install mariadb-1.0.7-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl -f ./ --no-index --no-deps
Looking in links: ./
Processing ./mariadb-1.0.7-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
Installing collected packages: mariadb
Successfully installed mariadb-1.0.7
```

From a file I created like this :

```
pi@PiMainServer:~ $ pip download mariadb -d '/home/pi/mariadb-deps'
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting mariadb
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/mariadb/mariadb-1.0.7-cp37-cp37m-l                                                                                                                                                             inux_armv7l.whl (235 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 235 kB 100 kB/s
Saved ./mariadb-deps/mariadb-1.0.7-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
Successfully downloaded mariadb
```

It seems I was just installing the connector, so I have managed to get the mariadb-server deb file, but when I try to install it, I get an error that it requires mariadb-server-10.3! I thought I was installing mariadb-server-10.3???
This is what I get:

```
pi@PTGM2:/var/cache/apt/archives $ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-server_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb10u1_all.deb
(Reading database ... 160964 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mariadb-server_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) over (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server
```

Ok, now I have installed mysql-common, mariadb-common and the connector, but I still get an error:

```
pi@PTGM2:/var/cache/apt/archives $ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-common_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb               10u1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-common.
(Reading database ... 160988 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mariadb-common_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-common (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) ...
Setting up mariadb-common (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (               my.cnf) in auto mode

pi@PTGM2:/var/cache/apt/archives $ sudo dpkg -i libmariadb3_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb10u               1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 160993 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmariadb3_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb10u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libmariadb3:armhf (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) over (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) ...
Setting up libmariadb3:armhf (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10+rpi1) ...
pi@PTGM2:/var/cache/apt/archives $ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-server_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb               10u1_all.deb
(Reading database ... 160993 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mariadb-server_1%3a10.3.29-0+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) over (1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1); however               :
  Package mariadb-server-10.3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server
```

Comment: I have no experience with mariadb, but I think you have only installed the mariadb connector for python. Here is the package you have installed: https://pypi.org/project/mariadb/

Comment: This might help with the server itself: https://howtoraspberrypi.com/mariadb-raspbian-raspberry-pi/

Comment: MarkO, I think you are correct, my next issue then is how to install mariadb-server without an internet connection! :-(

Comment: The first paragraph might help here: http://www.penguintutor.com/raspberrypi/apt-get-offline

Comment: You also have to install MariaDB Connector/C version 3.1.5 or later before installing mariadb python module.

Comment: George Richter, I'm not sure that I understand, have I not just installed a connector? what is the difference please?

Comment: I'm slowly working my way there...mariadb-server requires, mariadb-common requires, mysql-common etc... :-)